# "Error downloading from Xamarin server" when installing Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

So every time I try and install Xamarin, I get this error. Really have no idea what is going on, any help would be great. I am installing it on Windows 7 Enterprise, and I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Got this from the log file:

```
Error downloading from Xamarin server. Xamarin.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com'
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Full stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DownloadItem(DownloadServiceWorkItem item, Boolean firstDownload)

Error downloading from Xamarin server. Microsoft® MSBuild Tools 2015.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'download.microsoft.com'
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Full stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DownloadItem(DownloadServiceWorkItem item, Boolean firstDownload)

Error downloading from Xamarin server. Xamarin.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com'
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Full stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DownloadItem(DownloadServiceWorkItem item, Boolean firstDownload)

Error downloading from Xamarin server. Xamarin.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com'
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Full stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DownloadItem(DownloadServiceWorkItem item, Boolean firstDownload)

Installation of 'Xamarin' failed with more than one exception (attempt 3)
Errors while installing items.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Download failed.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem()
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
Download failed.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem()
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
Download failed.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Full stack trace:
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem()
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation issues like this are best handled directly by us (Xamarin Support) rather than posting here - StackOverflow is primarily for programming / code questions.

We would normally recommend trying a manual installation to start off with (installing each package separately).

It is important to note that Visual Studio 2012 support requires a legacy Xamarin Business / Enterprise license or one of the new Visual Studio / MSDN licenses.

The Community edition of Xamarin can be used with any non-express version of Visual Studio 2013 or any version of Visual Studio 2015.

Please reach out to contact@xamarin.com for assistance with this (please add the link to this question in your email) and we can send you the manual installation download links.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Visualstudio installer. Just uncheck Xamarin, then let it deinstall and then check it again. it helped me in Version 2017-2019 at least two times